# Shopify oAuth Implementation Security

Tags: oauth, shopify

So Egor exposes how anyone can use oAuth to easily hack services that implement oAuth poorly.

http://homakov.blogspot.ca/2012/07/saferweb-most-common-oauth2.html

Is Shopify aware of this, and can Shopify declare their usage of oAuth as secure from this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could check to which URL you are redirected after logging in on the Provider Authentication page. If it has got a `state` parameter with some random looking value in it, they are probably not affected. If they're missing it they are probably affected. You can though not be sure...